# Get button element and Style button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, android-webview

```
<input type="submit" name="$Submit$0" value="Log in">
```

How do I get element ID/Tag/Class from above type of button?
I want to style it too.

Is this correct?

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("submit") !== undefined || document.getElementsByClassName("submit") !== null) {
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("submit");
    for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        ele[i].style.color = "#6699FF";
        ele[i].style.padding = "0px";
        ele[i].style.height = "10px";
        ele[i].style.width = "30px";
    }
}
```

Or?

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName("submit") !== undefined || document.getElementsByTagName("submit") !== null) {
    var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("submit")[0];
    ele.style.color = "#6699FF";
    ele.style.padding = "0px";
    ele.style.height = "10px";
    ele.style.width = "30px";
}
```

getElementById won't work here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MarcusBrunsten I actually want to do this in Android WebView.

Comment: So you cant add your code to jsfiddle so we can help? Too bad...

Comment: @MarcusBrunsten I'll check out JSFiddle. Is it possible to use it in Android webview?

Comment: In this case, I needn't use JSFiddle. querySelectorAll (according to answer below) solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) never return `undefined` or `null`. The result returned is a HTMLCollection so you should check if this collection empty or not. Use `length` property:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("submit").length) {
    // ...
}
```

Note however that in your case, you should be checking type attribute of the button, not it's class or tag name.

For this another method is very convenient [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (collection):

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('[type=submit]').length) {}
```

or if you want to check only one button use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (single element):

```
if (document.querySelector('[type=submit]')) {}
```

Comment: yes in console I received [] as output.
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("submit").length);

Shows '0'. (alert for testing purpose only)

Comment: alert(document.querySelectorAll('[type=submit]').length); returns 1. Thanks a lot! Its working.

if (document.querySelectorAll('[type=submit]').length){ var x=document.querySelectorAll('[type=submit]'); x[0].style.color="#6699FF";}

It worked!

Comment: Why querySelectorAll isn't used instead of getElementsByTagName or getElementsByClassName ?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` was indrodused several years ago as more convenient and modern API. `getElementsByTagName` is a part of general DOM interface which is very old and ancient. So it's still widely used. There are also difference in the collections they return, but of course in most cases it's more convenient to go with `querySelectorAll`.